# How to callout to an action skill from a dialog skill in IBM watson?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have been trying to create a chat bot that helps users to interact with my website. I want Watson to be able to interact with my web-server to read, write or modify my database. In certain cases, Watson will require some very specific user inputs/Q&A which are too unordered to belong to any specific entity, for which I'm thinking an Action skill can help. After creating an Action skill that collects the desired user inputs, I'm now unable to find the option that let's you call an action skill from within a dialog node, or to callout for webhooks from an action skill.
Although some articles from the documentation says, it's possible to do so but I can't see from where. There used to be an option (**Call an action skill**) in the customize dialog box, [here is a screenshot of the old customize dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwrSy.png), but this option is not there anymore. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

IBM no longer provides the callout to actions skill from dialog skill. They posted alerts for existing users;-

Note: Once disabled, call out to an action skill will no longer be available.